# Insertion Sort Java Superposition

Tags: java, sorting

Here I have a new `array` that I've created:

> {18, 45, 33, 65, 76, 32, 96, 12, 46, 68}

Now, I'm using an insertion sort on this `array`. But I was wondering about something.

At some points we as humans cannot tell how many iterations have gone on in an `array` just by looking at it, right?

For example, imagine that at a point we have this newly made `array` after the program iterates over the `array` a few times using insertion sort:

> {18, 33, 45, 65, 76, 32, 96, 12, 46, 68}

Just by looking, isn't it impossible to know how many comparisons the computer made? I asked my teacher, and she says that looking at this new `array` it is obvious how many times that the new `array` was compared by the computer. I.E., just by looking at this new `array` my teacher could tell how many times it has been iterated upon.

How? Isn't it impossible to know for certain? She says that it is a specific number. Can someone explain how many times the new `array` has been compared?

Comment: Print the array after every iteration, there are finite number of iterations and thus a finite number of states. However, the array could be in that state for multiple iterations of an insertion sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible. You can sometimes pin it down fairly closely, particularly if you know the original array, but you can't get an exact number just by looking at the array state.

For example, if you don't know the original array state, and you look and see that the first 6 elements of the array are sorted, you could be looking at the state after the algorithm is done with the first 6 elements. However, it's also possible that those elements looked like that from the start, and you could be looking at the state before the algorithm has done anything, or after the algorithm has finished with the first 3 elements. All you really know is that it hasn't finished working with the 7th element yet.

If you do know the original array state, you can often tell exactly how much of the array has been sorted, and thus how many iterations have passed. However, not all iterations will affect the array state. For example, if the array was already sorted, the array state will never change. Also, it may be impossible to tell if the algorithm is in the middle of an iteration.

Comment: So my teacher is wrong, then? This was a test question, and we had two pieces of information(the two arrays it showed.) The question wanted us to tell how many iterations had occured. I said that it could not be determined. Which means that I am right, correct? That it cannot be fully determined simply by looking at those two pieces of knowledge.

Comment: @SulemanQamar: Knowing both the original and current states, and knowing that they are the particular states shown in your question, it's possible to tell that 2-4 iterations have passed (assuming your insertion sort variant starts with the second element on the first iteration). We can't determine anything more specific.

Comment: If your teacher taught some insertion sort variant that skips iterations that wouldn't do anything, you might be able to get more specific.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to determine the upper and lower bound number of comparisons done by the insertion sort algorithm for the case your provided. But it depends on the implementation. I will base my answer on the [pseudocode below](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#Algorithm_for_insertion_sort).

```
for i = 1 to length(A)
    j ← i
    while j > 0 and A[j-1] > A[j]
        swap A[j] and A[j-1]
        j ← j - 1
    end while
end for
```

If you take look at both states of the array, let's call the first state one

> {18, 45, 33, 65, 76, 32, 96, 12, 46, 68}

and the second state two,

> {18, 33, 45, 65, 76, 32, 96, 12, 46, 68}

you'll see that the change occurred at the beginning of the array on index 1 and 2.

The algorithm starts at index 1 and compares `arr[1]` with all its predecessors. This is only `arr[0]`, so there is 1 comparison and another if you count `j > 0`.
Since the previous element is smaller, not bigger, the while loop is left and the for loop starts its next iteration.

There `arr[2]`, which is 33, is compared to its predecessor `arr[1]`, since it is smaller, it is swapped. Then it is compared to `arr[0]`. It is bigger so the while is left.

This is the minimum that needs to be done to change the array from state one to state two. But the next two iterations of the algorithm, which would try to sort in 65 and 76, don't change the state and so it is entirely possible for the algorithm to have progressed until 76.

Only the next step would change the state further as it would sort in the 32.